# Express 4.0 and Passport - Redirect to Facebook not working

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I'm trying Express 4.0 with passport for a simple Facebook login.

```
    app.route('/auth/facebook')
    .get(function(req, res, next){
        console.log('Authentication start');

        var aut = passport.authenticate('facebook',
                             {
                                scope: ['read_stream',
                                        'publish_actions']
                             }, function(err) {

            });
     })
```

This route is supposed to redirect the browser to the Facebook page authentication, but instead nothing happens and the request goes timeout.
I'm trying to understand what changed in Express, because in the previous version everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You probably using `passport.session`, which has a dependency upon `express.session` being loaded.  If so, you have a block that looks like this someplace:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

2) `express.session` is [no longer part](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview) of the express core app.  To get sessions with Express v4, you can use the 'new' [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to keep things relatively continuous.

In a v4 app, you'll need to require the new `express-session` module and then use it in place of the original `express.session`.  The modified code would look a little like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')

var app = express()

app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat'}))
```

The `express-session` page (linked above) includes additional information on how to work with the module.

**The bottom line**: if you are building an Express v4 app while using examples that were written in Express v3, you'll want to carefully read the docs about the differences between Express versions and how to upgrade.  Most examples/docs out there assume Express v3, so you'll need to really understand these:

- [Migrating from 3.x to 4.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x)
- [New features in 4.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x)

Comment: I tried with a new expressJs 4 project, using the separated expression-session middleware but I get the same problem.

Comment: I have found an alternative to Passport that works with express 4 too, https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/

Comment: For replacing `express.session` with the new module?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you send query with `ajax`, try follow link:

```
 <a href="localhost:3000/auth/facebook">FB</a>
```

I use:

```
router.get('/facebook', function authenticate(req, res, next) {},
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));
```